# Add and delete books into this bookshelf vanilla javascript project

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this project I was supposed to add and delete books by author and title by pressing the submit and delete button.

There is [a video](https://www.loom.com/share/4ccc0b1199cb4aca8ae59ddfdfdbddfe) that illustrates how my project works.

I did it using two functions which saves the added books into an array of objects. I'm just starting to learn how to code so I'm looking for some other approaches to improve my way of thinking.

With nothing else to say other than thanks, this is the code I used:

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const library = document.querySelector(".library");
const inputAuthor = document.querySelector(".input-author");
const inputBook = document.querySelector(".input-book");
const errormessage = document.querySelector(".errormessage");
let storedBooks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
let bookShelf = [];
let filter = [];
let counter ="0"

function libraryBooks(object) {
  return  `<div class="${object.author}">
    <h1>${object.book}</h1>
    <p>${object.author}</p> 
    <hr> 
    <button class="remove">
    remove
    </button>
    </div>`
  }
  
function remove() {
  if(bookShelf.length>0){
    const removebtn = document.querySelectorAll(".remove");
    removebtn.forEach(element => element.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
      let parentNodeClass = element.parentNode.className;
      element.parentNode.remove()
      console.log(parentNodeClass)
      bookShelf = bookShelf.filter(x => x.author !== parentNodeClass)
      localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(bookShelf))
      console.log("book", bookShelf)
      console.log("store", storedBooks)
    })) 
  }
}


function add() {
  if(inputAuthor.value != "" && inputBook.value != ""){
    currentBook = []
    currentBook.push (
      {
        author: inputAuthor.value,
        book: inputBook.value
      }
    )
    filter = bookShelf.filter(x => x.book === currentBook[0].book)
    if(filter.length > 0){
      errormessage.style.display ="unset"
      inputAuthor.value = ""
      inputBook.value = ""
      setTimeout(()=>errormessage.style.display = "none",3000)
      return
    }
    bookShelf.push (
      {
        author: inputAuthor.value,
        book: inputBook.value
      }
    )   
    if(bookShelf.length>0) {
      currentBook.forEach(book => library.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', libraryBooks(book)))
    }
  } 
  inputAuthor.value = ""
  inputBook.value = ""
  localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(bookShelf))
}

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  add()
  remove()
}
)

if(storedBooks !== null){
   console.log("entré")
   bookShelf = storedBooks
   bookShelf.forEach(book => {
   library.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', libraryBooks(book))
   remove()
  })
}
```

```css
.form  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 24px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.errormessage {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Aweasome Books</h1>
    <section class="library">

    </section>
    <form class = "form">
    <input class="input-author" type="text" placeholder="Author">
        <input class="input-book" type="text" placeholder="book">
    <button type="submit">
            Add
        </button>
    </form>
    <div class="errormessage">Book was added previously on your bookshelf </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to start, the code snippet is not working so I can't really tell what your piece of software looks like upfront. But based on the code you shared, there are some things that I think can be improved. First is the way you structure your logic. You should avoid nested conditions (if else) if possible since it dilutes the way your code appears to others. One way you can avoid this is to use guards and early returns. You ought to use your if else statements appropriately by first identifying the worst-case scenarios and creating a condition (guard) to handle them. The way you do it is by putting them on top of all the remaining logic. That way, you can easily tell what that method is trying to do by removing the confusing part.